# Can't disable home as up on action bar

Tags: android

I am trying to disable the **home as up** on my **action bar**. Currently the action bar shows a back arrow (<-) I am trying to disable it like this I even try to set a different icon which doesn't show.

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_faq);
```

Comment: This should work  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` even if you set `android:parentActivityName` in the manifest.

Comment: @hegazy it looks like he has already put it in his code as mentioned in his post. Must be something else in his codes that forces the `?attr/homeAsUpIndicator` style element to appear. It looks like he is using AppCompat support library.

Comment: Please post us the complete code of your activity (atleast where you manage UI) and it's xml layout file.

Comment: Think eee might be on to something what would force ?attr/homeAsUpIndicator